# Vaadin: spacing with vertical scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, vaadin, padding, vertical-scroll

**Environment:**

- Vaadin 7.6.2
- no custom CSS rules so far besides for the headline
- Default theme in place: 'valo'.

**In a nutshell**

I have trouble with spacing while showing vertical scroll bars.
Let me show some pictures to demonstrate the problem:

[image][image]

Correct on the left, incorrect on the right.

**Description**

When no scroll bars are shown, the spacing (padding) is shown correctly on the left as well as on the right side horizontally (*refer to the red boxes*).
But as soon as the scroll bar gets visible, the spacing on the right between the Combobox and the scrollbar seems to be gone (*refer to the red strokes on the left in each picture as measurement line*).

However, if I add a margin (right) on the GridLayout containing the Combobox, the margin stays and behaves as expected when the scroll bars appears.

**Details**

The setup of the single components involved is as follows:

```
 --- Panel rightSection -------------------------
|                                                |
|  --- VerticalLayout componentContainer ------  |
| |                                            | |
| |  --- CustomComponent componentWrapper ---  | |
| | |                                        | | |
| | |  --- GridLayout grid ----------------  | | |
| | | |                                    | | | |
| | | |  --- Label headline -------------  | | | |
| | | | |                                | | | | |
| | | |  --------------------------------  | | | |
| | | |                                    | | | |
| | | |  --- ComboBox combobox ----------  | | | |
| | | | |                                | | | | |
| | | |  --------------------------------  | | | |
| | | |                                    | | | |
```

The crucial settings are as following:

```
rightSection.setSizeFull(); // Panel
componentContainer.setSizeFull(); // VerticalLayout
// the CustomComponent for being able to show the vertical scrollbars
//   as there is another component at the bottom of the 
//   componentContainer which has to be 
//   excluded of the vertical scrollbars
// therefore, in the constructor
CustomComponent(Component content) {
  addStyleName("v-scrollable");
  setCompositionRoot(content);
  setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
  setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
  content.setSizeUndefined();
  content.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
}

// make the customComponent take full space inside its parent
componentContainer.setExpandRatio(componentWrapper, 1); 
headline.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
combobox.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
```

**Finally**

How to preserve the space between the components inside the GridLayout and the vertical scrollbars (if present)?

As any time, any hint is appreciated :)

Cheers,
bully

Comment: The "padding" is done by CSS? And your try with "margin" is done by CSS or via GridLayout component's setMargin?

Comment: So far I tried everything without CSS, so the padding is handled by setSpacing(true) and the margin via setMargin(new MarginInfo(false, true, false, false))